# Can't download Xcode5 GM seed from my Mac Dev Account

Tags: ios, macos, ios7, xcode5

I've enrolled for **Mac Dev Program** ,in my Account I can't find Xcode5 GM seed which was released on 10th September 2013.

**Xcode Developer Preview 6**

**Posted Date:** August 21, 2013

**Build:** 5A11386k

**Included iOS SDK:** iOS 7 beta 5

**Included Mac SDK:** Mac OS X 10.9 beta

Can anyone suggest me How to get GM Seed?

Any help will be appreciated ,Thanks in advance.

Comment: Contact apple with that question.

Comment: MAC = Media Access Control address.

Comment: I was asking about Mac Dev Center John Topley

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple developer account support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## I found Solutions for it .

Apple has two different policies for Mac Dev ID & iOS Developer ID. If you've Enrolled for **Mac Developer program**, you can download every seeds related to OS X Preview.And IF you've enrolled for iOS Developer Program, you can download every seeds of iOS Development Tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it like under this page:

[image]

[image]

Comment: So I think Xcode5 GM seed is not for Mac Dev center because I can only see Xcode5 Dev preview 6 :(

Comment: Thanks incmiko.. But I'm thinking that it is not still available for Mac Dev ID